# Converting python time stamp to day of year

Tags: python, datetime

How can I convert a python timestamp into day of year:

```
Timestamp('2015-06-01 00:00:00')
```

I want a number where Jan 1 is 1, Jan 2 is 2... Dec 31 is 365 (for a non-leap year)

Comment: what do you mean ? do you want it to be a number where 0 is the first day of the year or do you want it to only include the date and not have the year ?

Comment: @Whud, I want a number where first day of year is 1...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the function [`datetime.timetuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple) which returns a [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object with your desired attribute. It has a named tuple interface, so you can access the values by index or attribute name.

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-06-01 00:00:00",
                                  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print date.timetuple().tm_yday
#=> 152
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can convert it to a `datetime.datetime` object like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
>>> s = "2015-06-01 00:00:00"
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format)
```

Now you can use the methods on `dt` to get what you want,except that `dt` doesn't have the function you want directly, so you need to convert to a time tuple

```
>>> tt = dt.timetuple()
>>> tt.tm_yday
152
```

Comment: I just copy the date from the question that's it. it is not a Plagiarism..and while answering I didn't see the above answer

Comment: I'm terribly sorry! I didn't realize at all the date was in the question. My apologies!