# Get day of year from python arrow

Tags: python, arrow-python

```
_date = '2017-03-17T00:00:00'

import arrow
arrow.get(_date)
```

How can I get day of year from the above code?

Comment: `arrow.get(_date).datetime.strftime('%j')` Put that expression inside `int()` if you need an integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get day of year from python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360943/get-day-of-year-from-python-datetime)

Comment: Nice timing on the deletion of your self-duplicate...

Comment: @AndrasDeak, sorry was not intentional.

Comment: also delete arrow tag

Comment: I'm still confused: You've asked this question at least 3 times now, gotten answers twice, accepted one once, and are still asking it.

Comment: For reference, [question from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073373/converting-python-time-stamp-to-day-of-year), same answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting python time stamp to day of year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073373/converting-python-time-stamp-to-day-of-year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for the arrow solution, but here as an alternative with datetime library.

As explained by: [Converting python time stamp to day of year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073373/converting-python-time-stamp-to-day-of-year) this would be the answer you are seeking:

```
import datetime
_date = '2017-03-17T00:00:00'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
print(dt.timetuple().tm_yday)
# prints 76
```

Comment: Arrow has the capability that they want built-in... they just haven't read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `arrow.now().format("DDDD")`.